# JGit: Count objects

Tags: java, git, jgit

How can I retrieve the total number of git objects in a repository? (I search something like the `git count-objects` in JGit.)

I made a Java program that calculates statistic values and has to read every object (blob, tree, commit, tag) of a git repository. Something like a progress bar should show the user how many objects already have been processed. So I need the total number of git objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not manipulate the Git objects at all, but I suppose you should explore the Repository object, which has methods like `getAllRefs()` or `getObjectDatabase()`.

From the results, I imagine you could find what you want.

Comment: I didn't found out how to get the number of `git count-objects` until now, but this answer was nevertheless very helpful for me.